# Any reason why I am told I have no internet connection when I type gmail.com into Chrome?

Tags: internet

Any reason why I am told I have no internet connection, but for Gmail only, not Google, Stack Exchange, etc? It just takes me to my router when I type in `gmail.com`.

The wifi icon on the top right says I'm still trying to connect.

This is only for Google Chrome, not Safari. I had just reset my public IP, for paranoid reasons, I won't explain, by leaving it off for 20 minutes.

I went to Gmail through Google rather than typing `gmail.com` and it worked. But still cannot do so directly.

`www.gmail.com` works, but now with the www prefix. I can assure you I have made no typos.

Everything else seems to work normally without the `www`, e.g. `google.com` takes me to Google.

Here's an example of trying this

[image]

Could this little kink be evidence of an *AI hack*?

Comment: I then turned my router off and on again (IP reset again) and I could not reach stackexchange until I googled it (now I can access it normally).

Comment: I don't think it's about Apple software, hardware or services. Is it?

Comment: iI have a macbook @Thinkr !

Comment: It's not because you *have* a MacBook and the issue happened there that it's about Apple software, hardware and services. For example, asking a question about how to configure your gmail rules in-website (but on Mac) would be off-topic.

Comment: where could it go @Thinkr

Comment: Can you or a mod migrate to super user please @Thinkr ?

Comment: You can flag you post and select "In need of a moderator intervention". Then describe why you want to move it. Mods will see it and decide whether or not to migrate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your router is trying to be helpful by acting as a captive portal of sorts when it is offline. Not very desirable in my opinion, but nothing nefarious. You can probably avoid this by setting your devices to use a different DNS service (like Google, Cloudflare, OpenDNS, …). You may also be able to turn off this behavior in your router’s web interface.

Once a device has successfully resolved a DNS name (because the router is inserting itself, it is deemed successful), the response will be cached for a certain amount of time. There could be multiple stacked caches, even on the same device. Only once all of them expire can you browse to the original site.

By requesting a different address (leaving out/adding `www.`, …), you are not hitting the cache.

You can clear the macOS DNS cache using the following command:

```
sudo dscacheutil -flushcache; sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
```

It is valid from 10.15 (Catalina).

---

So, no, this is not a hack and most certainly not at all related to artificial intelligence.

Comment: I will have to take your word for it, being so computer illiterate. Crisis over :D

Comment: flushed the dns and it is still happening, but not much of a mystery i'm sure